# Automatically running python script on raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run my python script automatically when the system reboots. I have followed a bunch of other threads about this topic and think i am close, but getting a permission denied error.

My script uses GPIO and Tkinter and is written in Python 3.2.3

The first step was i added this line to the top of my script.

```
#! /usr/bin python3.2
```

I saw other posts where they did /bin/etc python from what i can tell python is not installed here and throws other errors if i try to do that. I also tried just python instead of python 3.2 but i think i should have 3.2

I then went to the terminal and ran this command.

```
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/FDRT/stopclock.py
```

this returned immediately with out any errors.

I then modified LXDE autostart file

```
sudo nano ~/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

I added this line to the bottom.

```
/usr/bin/sudo ~/FDRT/stopclock.py
```

I then rebooted the pi and it didn't do anything 
in /home/pi I opened .xsession-errors file and see i have a permission denied error.

I then just tried to run the same command in the terminal window

```
/usr/bin/sudo ~/FDRT/stopclock.py
```

this returns the same permission denied error.

Could someone help me on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: add it to `/etc/rc.local`  ... thats the easiest way (and afaik thats always called ... ) (also dont lxde entries look like `@/usr/bin/sudo ...`) you should also always use fully qualified paths in those (ie `/home/pi/...` instead of `~`)

Comment: aditionally you can run this on the display from the terminal by using the environmental variable `export DISPLAY=:0` prior to running your script

Comment: `crontab -e `  then  `@reboot pth_to_your_script`

Comment: i tried fully qualified path. `/usr/bin/sudo /home/pi/FDRT/stopclock.py` this still results in permission denied. 

I changed the header of my script per Foon's suggestion to be `#!/usr/bin/python3.2` this errors. it is ok if i do `#!/usr/bin/ python3.2`

Comment: Padraic i tried the crontab approach first and ran into issues because of gpio and tkinter. The error returned from this was _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable.

I should point out if I run my script from IDLE 3 it runs fine.

Comment: I also tried adding this to /etc/rs.local wasn't sure what to add here so i put exactly what i put in the autostart file. this didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you're getting permission denied locally should make this easier to debug.  The first issue is that you appear to be missing a /
Change:

```
> #! /usr/bin python3.2
```

to

```
> #!/usr/bin/python3.2
```

Edit to respond to Joran's comment:

Note that if you have the following simple program (set to permission 755)

```
#! /usr/bin python
print "Hello world"
```

Running it as `python test.py` will print out hello world; running it as `./test.py` returns: `-bash: ./test.py: /usr/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied` (at least on my system; I thought I've seen just Permission denied elsewhere), which is why I was hoping this would resolve the issue without further tests (assuming that is how the OP had the shebang and wasn't just an artifact of pasting into SO)

Also, I'd suggest replacing the ~ with the real path (/home/pi) in your steps just to make sure somewhere something isn't expanding it to e.g. root's home (assuming /home/pi isn't root's home on a RPi)

Comment: while this may be correct... I dont know that it answers OP's question